# When using .append in Python item is getting appended multiple times. Why?

Tags: python, list, append

I am using `.append` to fill in an empty list with a string but my item is being appended multiple times. After the first string is appended 5 times and the second string is appended 4 times. Why is this happening?

Here is the code I am using

```
kw_list_1 = []


def add_kw():
    kw_1 = raw_input('enter your first keyword - ')

    for kw in kw_1:
        kw_list_1.append(kw_1)


    kw_2 = raw_input('enter second keyword - ')

    for kw2 in kw_2:
        kw_list_1.append(kw_2)

    print kw_list_1
```

For example, if I use `'apple'` for `kw_1` and `'pear'` for `kw_2` this is returned

```
['apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'pear', 'pear', 'pear', 'pear']
```

What's going on here? Is append not the correct way to approach this?

Comment: Why are you using the for loops here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's due to the `for` loop.

```
  for kw in kw_1:
            kw_list_1.append(kw_1)
```

just use `kw_list_1.append(kw_1)` remove the for loop.

Answer (score 9):

These two lines:

```
for kw in kw_1:
    kw_list_1.append(kw_1)
```

You are looping over `kw_1`, which is a string, so your loop body is executed once for each character in the string.  The loop body appends the entire string to the list.  So if you input `"apple"`, you will append `"apple"` to the list five times.  `"pear"` will be appended four times.

Comment: Furthermore, the fact that you're not using the thing that changes with each loop, `kw`, should be a tip off. If you were appending that instead, you'd see `['a', 'p', 'p', 'l', ...`.

Comment: Great, thanks for the explanation. I didn't realize that the loop would react that way.

Answer (score 0):

This program worked for me

```
kw_list_1 = []
def add_kw():
    kw_1 = raw_input('enter your first keyword - ')
    kw_list_1.append(kw_1)
    kw_2 = raw_input('enter second keyword - ')
    kw_list_1.append(kw_2)
    print kw_list_1
add_kw()
```

The loops were causing the fruit to appear as many times as the characters in the string